# need to add Quill Rich Text Editor into form

Tags: javascript, quill

Need to integrate Quill Rich Text Editor into the form.

Instead of a textarea, it shows div as below.

```html
<div class="snow-container border rounded p-50">
    <div class="compose-editor mx-75"></div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
        <div class="compose-quill-toolbar pb-0">
            <span class="ql-formats mr-0">
                <button class="ql-bold"></button>
                <button class="ql-italic"></button>
                <button class="ql-underline"></button>
                <button class="ql-link"></button>
                <button class="ql-image"></button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Need to send data to form with name as message in post method.

Normally in text area we can just give textarea name

How to do it. Need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [hidden `<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden) to submit the contents of the editor using a form. Place the input into your form, set a `name`, then update the `value` with Javascript whenever the content of the editor changes. The value of the input will be automatically submitted with the form.

```html
<script>
// ... set up quill

// query the input element (use whatever method you prefer)
let inputElement = document.getElementById('hidden-input')
quill.on('text-change', function() {
  // sets the value of the hidden input to
  // the editor content in Delta format
  inputElement.value = JSON.stringify(quill.getContents())

  // you can alternatively use
  // inputElement.value = quill.root.innerHTML
  // if you want the data as HTML
});

</script>

<form>
  <!-- other form stuff -->
  <input type='hidden' name='richText' id='hidden-input'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucion **FORM QUILL EDITOR:**

Link CSS:

```
<!-- CSS Implementing Plugins -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://htmlstream.com/preview/front-v4.2/html/assets/css/vendor.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://htmlstream.com/preview/front-v4.2/html/assets/vendor/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<!-- CSS Front Template -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://htmlstream.com/preview/front-v4.2/html/assets/css/theme.min.css?v=1.0">
```

Link JS:

```
<!-- JS Implementing Plugins -->
<script src="https://htmlstream.com/preview/front-v4.2/html/assets/js/vendor.min.js"></script>
<!-- JS Front -->
<script src="https://htmlstream.com/preview/front-v4.2/html/assets/js/theme.min.js"></script>
```

En mi html:

```
<form id="form-perfil" name="form-perfil" method="POST">
  <!-- Form Group -->
  <div class="row form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label input-label">BIO</label>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <!-- Quill -->
      <div class="quill-custom">
        <div
          class="js-quill"
          style="min-height: 15rem;"
          data-hs-quill-options='{
                       "placeholder": "Type your message...",
                        "modules": {
                          "toolbar": [
                            ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "link", "image", "blockquote", "code", {"list": "bullet"}]
                          ]
                        }
                       }'
        >
          Creative mind at Htmlstream
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Quill -->
      <textarea name="text_quill" style="display: none;" id="text_quill"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Form Group -->

  <button type="submit" class="mt-3 float-right btn btn-primary">Enviar formulario</button>
  <!-- End Form Group -->
</form>
```

En mi JS:

```
// INITIALIZATION OF QUILLJS EDITOR
// =======================================================
var quill = $.HSCore.components.HSQuill.init('.js-quill');

// =======================================================
$("#form-perfil").on("submit", function (e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); //No se activará la acción predeterminada del evento

  $("#text_quill").val($(".ql-editor").html());

  var formData = new FormData($("#form-perfil")[0]);
  $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/pago_administrador.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (datos) {  },             
  });
});
```